# How to generate maximum busload 1000Mbps on ethernet port of CANoe

Tags: ethernet, canoe

My target is: CANoe hardware can **send full busload (1000Mbps) ethernet packet** to **a specific IP** on our board.

I tried to generate EthernetPacket using hardware interface.
However, the ethernet packet can not be sent to the specific IP. My board (IP: 192.168.1.6) is not received the the ethernet packet.

This is my hardware setup:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdavS.png)

If I select MAC address as destination instead of IP address, I can send 1000Mbps and our board can receive the packet but the packet still lost when speed > 300Mbps. With iperf3 tool we can check the ethernet interface on our board can run full busload.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utp4l.png)

So my issues:

1. The ethernet packet can not be sent to a specific IP on our board.
2. The packet is lost when the speed > 300Mbps.

This is my code of CANoe:

```
void StressStart()
{
  const int SIZE = 1000;
  char gTxBuffer[SIZE];

  ethernetPacket gStressTxPacket;
  
  long transmissionRate;
  ip_Address sourceAddress, destinationAddress;
  char addrStr[20];
  long result;
  
  // set Ethernet packet data
  gStressTxPacket.msgChannel  = 1;
  gStressTxPacket.hwPort      = lookupEthernetPort ("Bus_Eth1_2::Port3");
  //gStressTxPacket.source      = EthGetMacAddressAsNumber( "02:84:CF:3B:BE:03" );
  //gStressTxPacket.destination = EthGetMacAddressAsNumber( "e6:70:e6:77:b5:42" );
  gStressTxPacket.Length      = SIZE;
  gStressTxPacket.type        = 0x0800;
  
  // initialize packet with IPv4 and UDP protocols
  gStressTxPacket.udp.Init();

  // set IPv4 addresses
  gStressTxPacket.ipv4.source.ParseAddress( "192.168.1.10" );
  gStressTxPacket.ipv4.destination.ParseAddress ( "192.168.1.6" );

  // set UDP ports
  gStressTxPacket.udp.source = 3001;
  gStressTxPacket.udp.destination = 3002;
  
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    gTxBuffer[i] = 'a';
  }
  
  // set UDP payload
  gStressTxPacket.udp.SetData( 0, gTxBuffer, SIZE );

  // calculate UDP and IPv4 checksum and send Ethernet packet
  gStressTxPacket.CompletePacket();

  transmissionRate = 20000;
  result = EthStartPacketGenerator( gStressTxPacket, transmissionRate);
  
  if (result != 0) {
    write("<%BASE_FILE_NAME%> Can not start generate, error: %d", result);
  }
}
```

Could you check my issues!
Thank you very much!

CANoe hardware can **send full busload (1000Mbps) ethernet packet** to **a specific IP** on our board.